# Different style for frontmatter chapters in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents

I am looking for a way to change the style of chapters in the TOC that belong to the front matter. Below I posted a minimal example code to illustrate my goal:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\chapter{Preface}
\chapter{Acknowledgements}
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{First Chapter}
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\end{document}
```

Here, I would like to have the two frontmatter chapters Preface and Acknowlegements to be written in non-bold italics in the TOC, including their page numbers. I manage to write their names in the required style by simply using e.g.

```
\chapter[\itshape\textmd{Preface}]{Preface}
```

but this does not change the formatting of the page number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I define a new cs `\matter@switch` and appended it to the `chapterentry` KOMA font. Then I added macros to `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` which write a redefinition of `\matter@switch` to the toc file. (I'm sure the code below can be optimized)

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\matter@switch{}
\addtokomafont{chapterentry}{\matter@switch}
\g@addto@macro\frontmatter{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\renewcommand\protect\matter@switch{\normalfont\itshape}%
  }%
}
\g@addto@macro\mainmatter{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\renewcommand\protect\matter@switch{}%
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Preface}
\chapter{Acknowledgements}
\mainmatter
\chapter{First Chapter}
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved by changing the chapter title font/page fonts using the `tocloft` package and its various commands, `\cftchapterfont` and `\cftchapterpagefont`. However, this commands persist until explicitly changed while the ToC is processed. Therefore
it's necessary to write the switch back  commands directly to the ToC using `\addtocontents`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}%
\begin{document}
\let\cftchapfontorig\cftchapfont
\let\cftchappagefontorig\cftchappagefont
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\itshape}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\itshape}%
\frontmatter
\chapter{Preface}
\chapter{Acknowledgements}
\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\cftchapfontorig}}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\cftchappagefontorig}}
\mainmatter
\chapter{First Chapter}
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you heard of `\setkomafont` and `\usekomafont`? This seems to be more appropriate than using a package.

Comment: What would be the names of the elements I have to change when using '\setkomafont'? I didn't find a comprehensive list in the koma documentation to figure out the name of the respective toc elements.

Comment: @shiin: This should be answered by Henri Menke -- I provided a solution without `\setkomafont` -- it should work for other documentsclasses as well

Comment: @HenriMenke I tried using `\setkomafont{chapterentry}{\sffamily\itshape}` and `\setkomafont{chapterentrypagenumber}{\sffamily\itshape}`. While this changes the style, it's a global change and cannot simply be changed back for the chapters in the main matter.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I just tested the tocloft package. It doesn't seem to be a good solution for various reasons: a) It does not respect the default settings of scrbook (e.g. non-serif page numbers for chapters), and more imporantly b) the toc is no longer considered as a separate chapter (starting on a right page with a chapter header, a pdf bookmark, ...).