# Different style for backmatter chapters in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, tocloft

I am looking for a way to make both frontmatter and backmatter chapters non-bold italic in the Table of Contents.

For the frontmatter chapters, I found a short and well-working solution here by Christian Hupfer: [Different style for frontmatter chapters in TOC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201402/different-style-for-frontmatter-chapters-in-toc?noredirect=1&lq=1)

It uses the `tocloft` package and its commands `\cftchapterfont` and `\cftchapterpagefont`.

My question is how to extend this to work for the backmatter chapters too?

Answer (score 1):

Just redefine the `\appendix` macro in the same way if you're using KOMA like the OP of the linked question:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\matter@switch{}
\addtokomafont{chapterentry}{\matter@switch}
\g@addto@macro\frontmatter{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\renewcommand\protect\matter@switch{\normalfont\itshape}%
  }%
}
\g@addto@macro\mainmatter{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\renewcommand\protect\matter@switch{}%
  }%
}
\g@addto@macro\appendix{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\renewcommand\protect\matter@switch{\normalfont\itshape}%
  }%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Preface}
\chapter{Acknowledgements}
\mainmatter
\chapter{First Chapter}
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\appendix
\chapter{Appendix}
\end{document}
```

Or introduce similar code if you're not using KOMA but `tocloft`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}%
\begin{document}
\let\cftchapfontorig\cftchapfont
\let\cftchappagefontorig\cftchappagefont
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\itshape}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\itshape}%
\frontmatter
\chapter{Preface}
\chapter{Acknowledgements}
\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchapfont}{\cftchapfontorig}}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchappagefont}{\cftchappagefontorig}}
\mainmatter
\chapter{First Chapter}
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchapfont}{\itshape}}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchappagefont}{\itshape}}
\appendix
\chapter{Appendix}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another suggestion using package `tocbasic`.

With a **KOMA-Script class**:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}% loads tocbasic automatically

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  entryformat=\chapterentryformat,
  pagenumberformat=\chapterentryformat
]{tocline}{chapter}
\newif\ifmainmatterintoc
\newcommand*\chapterentryformat[1]
  {{\ifmainmatterintoc\usekomafont{chapterentry}\else\normalfont\slshape\fi#1}}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\chapter{Preface}
\chapter{Acknowledgements}
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\mainmatterintoctrue}
\chapter{First Chapter}
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\backmatter
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\mainmatterintocfalse}
\chapter{First Backmatter Chapter}
\chapter{Second Backmatter Chapter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With a **standard class**:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  entryformat=\chapterentryformat,
  pagenumberformat=\chapterentryformat
]{tocline}{chapter}
\newif\ifmainmatterintoc
\newcommand*\chapterentryformat[1]
  {{\ifmainmatterintoc\bfseries\sffamily\else\normalfont\slshape\fi#1}}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\chapter{Preface}
\chapter{Acknowledgements}
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\mainmatterintoctrue}
\chapter{First Chapter}
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\backmatter
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\mainmatterintocfalse}
\chapter{First Backmatter Chapter}
\chapter{Second Backmatter Chapter}
\end{document}
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

It is also possible to patch `\mainmatter` and `\appendix` in the preamble:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  entryformat=\chapterentryformat,
  pagenumberformat=\chapterentryformat
]{tocline}{chapter}
\newif\ifmainmatterintoc
\newcommand*\chapterentryformat[1]
  {{\ifmainmatterintoc\bfseries\sffamily\else\normalfont\slshape\fi#1}}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptocmd\mainmatter{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\mainmatterintoctrue}}
  {}{\mmPatchFailed}
\xapptocmd\backmatter{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\mainmatterintocfalse}}
  {}{\appPatchFailed}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\chapter{Preface}
\chapter{Acknowledgements}
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{First Chapter}
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\backmatter
\chapter{First Backmatter Chapter}
\chapter{Second Backmatter Chapter}
\end{document}
```